# When clicking on button like showcaps,small,number no change is happening to the div in html, visibility not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

1. stack.html:
   when clicking on the button show caps,show small,show number nothing will happening,showcaps only dispaly kcaps div but now it display all the divs.iam expecting a result such that showcaps only display the kcaps div,similarly showsmall displays ksmall,shownumber displays knumber.The java script file(ext.js) should be an external file,that must be kept separate.

   ```
       <html>
       <head>
       <script src="ext.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
       <!--Caps Div-->
       <div class="bttn1" id="kcaps">
       <button class="CSSButton" id="A">A</button>
        </div>
       <div class="bttn2" id="ksmall">
       <button class="CSSButton" id="a">a</button>
        </div>
       <div class="bttn3" id="knumber">
       <button class="CSSButton" id="0">0</button>
        </div>
       <button type="button" id="ckey"/> Show caps </button>
       <button type="button" id="skey"/> Show small </button>
       <button type="button" id="nkey"/> Show number </button>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```
2. ext.js:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   document.getElementById('ckey').addEventListener('click', showElem);
   document.getElementById('skey').addEventListener('click', showElem2);
   document.getElementById('nkey').addEventListener('click', showElem3); 
   });
   function showElem(e)
   {
   document.getElementById('kcaps').style.visibility. = "visible";
   document.getElementById('ksmall').style.visibility = "hidden"; 
   document.getElementById('knumber').style.visibility = "hidden";  
   }
   function showElem2(e)
   {
   document.getElementById("kcaps").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("ksmall").style.visibility="visible"; 
   document.getElementById("knumber").style.visibility="hidden"; 
   }
   function showElem3(e)
   {
   document.getElementById("kcaps").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("ksmall").style.visibility="hidden"; 
   document.getElementById("knumber").style.visibility="visible"; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using wrong id:-

In your html the if of the buttons are ckey, skey, nkey

and in the javascript file you've written:-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById('ckeys').addEventListener('click', showElem);
document.getElementById('skeys').addEventListener('click', showElem2);
document.getElementById('nkeys').addEventListener('click', showElem3); 
});
```

You should write:- ckey instead of ckeys and so on.

And remove the extra . in showElem function

```
function showElem(e)
 {
 document.getElementById('kcaps').style.visibility.(* extra dot should be removed) = "visible";
```

Comment: Indra has it right. Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37CeZ/ Also you're closing some of the button tags in your HTML wrong.